# add spell check to contextmenu in Geckofx

Tags: c#, firefox, xulrunner, gecko, geckofx

I am trying to integrate Mozilla Firefox into C# winform application. i downloaded the xulrunner(v1.1.19) and geckofx

Everything is running fine but
i want to add default Mozilla dictionary/spelling check option to the context menu just as default Mozilla....??? how to do it

Comment: @Sire it was a very hectic job that i did. i used MOZNET http://se7en-soft.com/software/moznet/features.aspx

Comment: @Sire it was a very hectic job that i did. i used MOZNET library 
http://se7en-soft.com/software/moznet/features.aspx
important thing to remember they use xulrunner 3.2.67 engine which is not the latest Mozilla xulrunner engine. I had one compatibility issue with this library every thing else worked fine. i hope it helps . but i could not find out any other solution to do this without MOZNET library and i am not xulrunner programmer. i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

These [SpellCheckEngine unittests](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-16.0/src/7aa09406185bffd3af8d3b98f37648193c34645c/GeckofxUnitTests/SpellCheckerEngineTests.cs?at=default) from [geckofx-16.0](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-16.0) may point you in the right direction.

They provide some example of how to manipulate the spell checking engine.